# How to strip out all characters except for numbers, letters, quotes, and colons/semi-colons?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a document that I'm parsing text out of - I'm trying to figure out how to use this RegEx expression to take out everything that isn't alphanumeric, but I want to keep quotes, ampersands and colons/semi-colons.

```
               s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\w-]+", " ");
```

How can I add a replace all of these "except these" pattern here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put all those exceptional cases into the character class.

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\w'""&:;-]+", " ");
```

Comment: I think you need to escape that " even with the literal string identifier. Dont remember what the escape is, I think its """

Comment: Thanks guys, worked great. I didn't need to add any escape characters to the sequence - maybe it was added in the sample above that I used.